# Draw a diagonal line from a specific geom_point() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to draw a diagonal line starting from a specific `geom_point()` in ggplot2. The line would start from the point (`x = 21`, `y = 0.37`) and end at the diagonal line produced between the first and the last point (see below:)

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(x = c(0, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 33.33), y = c(0.2, 
                                                                       0.212, 0.22, 0.26, 0.339, 0.452, 0.654, 1.001, 1.155)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(df, row_number() %in% c(1, n())), method = "lm") +
  geom_point(aes(x = 21, y = .37), shape = 21, size = 4, fill = "blue") +
  theme_light()
#> Warning in qt((1 - level)/2, df): NaNs produced
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**EDIT:**

Example of the result I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Diagonal as in orthogonal to the blue line?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good looking solution for a reason that I will explain later. But it does exactly what the question is asking for.

First, an auxiliary function.

```
#
# computes the intersection point of the 
# line passing through x perpendicular to
# the line defined by PQ
#
perp_line <- function(x, P, Q){
  a <- Q[2] - P[2]
  b <- -(Q[1] - P[1])
  A <- matrix(c(a, b, b, -a), nrow = 2)
  c1 <- -b*P[2] - a*P[1]
  c2 <- -b*x[1] + a*x[2]
  cc <- c(-c1, -c2)
  solve(A, cc)
}
```

Now use the function to get the coordinates of the required point and draw a line segment from the blue point to the computed one.

```
X <- unlist(df[1, ])
Y <- unlist(df[nrow(df), ])
Z <- perp_line(c(21, 0.37), X, Y)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(df, row_number() %in% c(1, n())), method = "lm") +
  geom_point(aes(x = 21, y = .37), shape = 21, size = 4, fill = "blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x2, y = y2, xend = Z[1], yend = Z[2])) +
  #coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  theme_light()
```

As you can see from the graph, the aspect ratio is terrible. Your `x` and `y` axis ranges are so different that the lines seem anything but perpendicular. Uncomment the `coord_fixed` code line to get a better aspect ratio but then you will not be able to see anything.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Rui! in geom_segment() do you mean Z instead of P? and another thing: I guess I couldn't explain well, this line has to be in a 90 degree angle in relation to the other line (between the first and last point)

Comment: @FMM Right, sorry, it's `Z`, not `P`. (It was `P` in a test version.) As for the angle, that *is* a 90 degrees angle, it just doesn't seem to be due to the aspect ratio. At least, that line is the geometric solution. A solution that *looks* right but is not is a different problem. I guess it would have to do with optical illusions, not my strong.